# Unable to connect Google App to Google MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform

- my app is deployed and responds (however, no db connection) but, the pages that do not connect to the database work correctly, including calls to the web service api
- my mysql database is running and has a public ip address (also, added my ip address as an authorized network)
- i can connect to the google database from my local laptop using the mysql workbench and the instance i created is fully loaded and ready
- i am able to run my .net core 3.1 project from my local machine and it runs using the Google MySQL instance via the public ip address

unsure why i am able to run my app locally using the google mysql instance from my laptop but the app from within the google hosting network itself does not.

[google claims it should work by default?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0Auc.png)

however, the only way i have gotten it to work is by adding 0.0.0.0/0 to the allowed network. seems "dirty" that way. but, if i must.

connection string is "Server=34.125.xxx.xxx;Database=testdb;Uid=root;Password=testpword"

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8EWK.png)

Comment: I'd suggest to check the documentation first since the method you're using to connect is not the appropriate https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard#connecting_to

Comment: Also you're not mentioning if it is GAE Flex or Standard

Answer (score 0):

You have already gone through the issue yourself. You have tried to make `0.0.0.0/0` an authorized network and it worked! what does this mean? This simply means that you need to authorize the AppEngine outbound NAT gateway `cidr` to access your `CloudSQL` instance and it worked because this NAT `cidr` is included in `0.0.0.0/0` as you may already know.

---

**but the thing is, this is not the best option to secure your connection to `CloudSQL`**.

As quoted from the documentation:

> Using the Cloud SQL Auth proxy is the recommended method for authenticating connections to a Cloud SQL instance because it's the most secure method.

> The CloudSQL Auth proxy provides secure access to your instances without a need for Authorized networks or for configuring SSL.

See the CloudSQL Auth proxy documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy)

---

Also,

> You do not need to use the Cloud SQL Auth proxy or configure SSL to connect to Cloud SQL from App Engine standard environment or App Engine flexible environment.

See

[Connecting from AppEngine standard environment to CloudSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard)
and [Connecting from AppEngine flexible environment to CloudSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-flexible)